# Install Exchange Server 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: exchange-server, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2012-r2

I am completely new to servers. And I run into a problem that I need to install Exchange Server 2013 on my server. 
When I try to install this server it gives me an error

```
Error:
The Active Directory schema isn't up-to-date, and this user account isn't a member of the 'Schema Admins' and/or 'Enterprise Admins' groups.
```

I looked through numerous tutorials and I am pretty sure that I did everything right.[image]

As you can see my account is a member of domain admins and enterprise admins as well. 
P.S. I am using Google Compute Engine

Answer (score 0):

As it says, you need to add your account to Schema Admins. Add it the same way you added Enterprise Admins. Schema Admins is not inherited by Enterprise Admins, they're separate roles.